# Kali linux dual boot with win 8 64 bit is not working

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot, 64bit, kali-linux

I have Windows 8 64-bit installed on my Lenovo Ideapad. I tried to install Kali Linux to dual boot with Windows by downloading Kali Linux 1.0.5 32-Bit ISO and then burning it into my USB stick using LinuxLive USB Creator 2.8.27. But when I tried to run the USB stick, it throws an error `You are running 32 bit version of image into 64 bit` which is completely correct.

After this, I downloaded Kali Linux 1.0.5 64-Bit and followed the same procedure but this time I am getting this error:

[image]

Is it possible to install Kali Linux to dual boot with Windows 8 64-bit? If yes, then which version of Kali Linux is supported?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having is with Debian-Installer loader. Try booting to the USB stick rather than using that program.

When your computer boots up, enter the BIOS and find something along the lines of 'Boot Manager'. Change the priority to boot to your USB stick first. Save & exit and it should boot properly.

Comment: I also did that but nothing happened ..

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the Debian-Installer loader doesn't seem to support your Windows version.

> Is it possible to install Kali Linux to dual boot with Windows 8 64-bit?

Yes, it is possible, I don't see why it wouldn't be possible.

I'd recommend you to burn the ISO image to your USB stick with [Win32 Disk Imager](https://launchpad.net/win32-image-writer).
**Note:** as far as I remember, Win32 Disk Imager doesn't show ISO images when browsing for the image to be burned to USB stick, but you can just type the path of the ISO image to the Image File -prompt (of course you can also copy&paste the path of the ISO to the prompt).

> If yes, then which version of Kali Linux is supported?

All versions of Kali Linux are supported: since your system (processor) is 64-bit, you can install either 64-bit or 32-bit version of Kali Linux to your system.